# What is the cause of my segment fault in C?

Tags: c, arrays, segmentation-fault, file-pointer

When I compile my code, I get no errors. However, when I attempt to run it, I get a segmentation fault (core dumped). Here is my main:

#### Original code

```
void main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    if(argc < 3){
          return;
    }

    char *stop_list_name = argv[1];
    char *doc_names[argc - 2];

    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < argc; i++){
            doc_names[i] = argv[i];
    }

//create the array of stop words
    char *stopWords[50];
    char *word;
    int word_counter = 0;
    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen(stop_list_name, "r");
    if(fp != NULL){
            while(!feof(fp)){
                    fscanf(fp, "%s", word);
                    stopWords[word_counter] = word;
                    word_counter++;
            }
    }

    fclose(fp);

    for(i = 0; stopWords[i] != '\0'; i++){
            printf("%s", stopWords[i]);
    }
}
```

I'm pretty sure something is wrong in my `while` loop, but I don't exactly know what, or how to fix it.

#### Amended code

After seeing the answers, I modified my code so it looks like this, but it still crashes.  What's wrong now?

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    if(argc < 3){
            return;
    }

    char *stop_list_name = argv[1];
    char *doc_names[argc - 2];

    int i;
    for(i = 2; i < argc; i++){
            doc_names[i-2] = argv[i];
    }

//create the array of stop words
    enum {MAX_STOP_WORDS = 50};
    char *stopWords[MAX_STOP_WORDS];
    int word_counter = 0;
    FILE *fp = fopen(stop_list_name, "r");
    if(fp != NULL){
            char word[64];
            int i;
            for(i = 0; i < MAX_STOP_WORDS && fscanf(fp, "%63s", word) == 1; i++){
                    stopWords[i] = strdup(word);
            }

            word_counter = i;
            fclose(fp);
    }

    for(i = 0; stopWords[i] != '\0'; i++){
            printf("%s", stopWords[i]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Problems in the original code

One possible source of problems is:

```
char *doc_names[argc - 2];

int i;
for(i = 0; i < argc; i++){
        doc_names[i] = argv[i];
}
```

You allocate space for `argc-2` pointers and proceed to copy `argc` pointers into that space.  That's a buffer overflow (in this case, a stack overflow too).   It can easily cause the trouble.  A plausible fix is:

```
for (i = 2; i < argv; i++)
    doc_names[i-2] = argv[i];
```

However, you really don't need to copy the argument list; you can just process the arguments from index 2 to the end.  I note that the code shown doesn't actually use `doc_names`, but the out-of-bounds assignment can still cause trouble.

---

You are not allocating space to read a word into, nor allocating new space for each stop word, nor do you ensure that you do not overflow the bounds of the array in which you're storing the words.

Consider using:

```
enum { MAX_STOP_WORDS = 50 };
char *stopWords[MAX_STOP_WORDS];
int word_counter = 0;
FILE *fp = fopen(stop_list_name, "r");
if (fp != NULL)
{
    char word[64];
    for (i = 0; i < MAX_STOP_WORDS && fscanf(fp, "%63s", word) == 1; i++)
        stopWords[i] = strdup(word);
    word_counter = i;
    fclose(fp);
}
```

This diagnosed problem is definitely a plausible cause of your crash.  I used `i` (declared earlier in the code) in the loop because `word_counter` makes the loop control line too long for SO.

Strictly, `strdup()` is not a part of standard C, but it is a part of POSIX.  If you don't have POSIX, you can write your own:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char *strdup(const char *str)
{
    size_t len = strlen(str) + 1;
    char *result = malloc(len);
    if (result != 0)
        memmove(result, str, len);
    return result;
}
```

---

You also have some other bad practices on display:

- [`while (!feof(file))` is always wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/while-feof-file-is-always-wrong).
- [What should `main()` return in C and C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/204476/what-should-main-return-in-c-and-c/)
- You should only call `fclose(fp)` if the `fopen()` worked, so you need to move the `fclose()` inside the `if` statement body.

---

#### Problems in the amended code

There's one important and a couple of very minor problems in the amended code:

- Your loop that prints the stop words depends on a null pointer (curiously spelled as `'\0'` — it is a valid but unconventional spelling for a null pointer), but the initialization code doesn't set a null pointer.

  There are (at least) two options for fixing that:

  1. Add a null pointer:

     ```
        for (i = 0; i < MAX_STOP_WORDS-1 && fscanf(fp, "%63s", word) == 1; i++)
            stopWords[i] = strdup(word);

        stopWords[i] = 0;
        fclose(fp);
     }

     for (i = 0; stopWords[i] != '\0'; i++)
         printf("%s\n", stopWords[i]);
     ```

     Note that the upper bound is now `MAX_STOP_WORDS - 1`.
  2. Or you can use `wordCount` instead of a condition:

     ```
     for (i = 0; i < wordCount; i++)
         printf("%s\n", stopWords[i]);
     ```

  I'd choose the second option.
- One reason for doing that is it avoids warnings about `wordCount` being set and not used — a minor problem.
- And `doc_names` is also set but not used.

I worry about those because my default compiler options generate errors for unused variables — so the code doesn't compile until I fix it.   That leads to:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if (argc < 3)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s stop-words docfile ...\n", argv[0]);
        return 1;
    }

    char *stop_list_name = argv[1];
    char *doc_names[argc - 2];

    int i;
    for (i = 2; i < argc; i++)
    {
        doc_names[i - 2] = argv[i];
    }
    int doc_count = argc - 2;

    // create the array of stop words
    enum { MAX_STOP_WORDS = 50 };
    char *stopWords[MAX_STOP_WORDS];
    int word_counter = 0;
    FILE *fp = fopen(stop_list_name, "r");
    if (fp != NULL)
    {
        char word[64];
        int i;
        for (i = 0; i < MAX_STOP_WORDS && fscanf(fp, "%63s", word) == 1; i++)
            stopWords[i] = strdup(word);

        word_counter = i;
        fclose(fp);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < word_counter; i++)
        printf("stop word %d: %s\n", i, stopWords[i]);

    for (i = 0; i < doc_count; i++)
        printf("document %d: %s\n", i, doc_names[i]);

    return 0;
}
```

And, given a stop words file containing:

```
help
able
may
can
it
should
do
antonym
prozac
```

and compiling it (source file `sw19.c`, program `sw19`) with:

```
$ gcc -O3 -g -std=c11 -Wall -Wextra -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes \
>     -Wold-style-definition -Werror sw19.c -o sw19
```

and running it as:

```
$ ./sw19 stopwords /dev/null
stop word 0: help
stop word 1: able
stop word 2: may
stop word 3: can
stop word 4: it
stop word 5: should
stop word 6: do
stop word 7: antonym
stop word 8: prozac
document 0: /dev/null
$
```

Comment: I made the changes recommended, except the segmentation fault is still present... am I missing something?

Comment: @user2877117: I've updated my answer to include an explanation for the crash in your revised code.  You need to learn how to debug such problems for yourself, though.  Either use a debugger and step through the code, or learn how to use diagnostic print statements to print progress and variables at key points in the code (or, better, learn both techniques for debugging).

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to store the scanned string to an uninitialized pointer,

```
fscanf(fp, "%s", word);
```

and `word`, is not even initialized.

You could use a static buffer for that, just like this

```
char word[100];

if (fscanf(fp, "%99s", word) != 1)
    word[0] = '\0'; /* ensure that `word' is nul terminated on input error */
```

Also, `while (!feof(fp))` is wrong, because the `EOF` marker wont be set until `fscanf()` attempts to read past the end of the file, so the code will iterate one extra time. And in that case you would store the same `word` twice.

Note that you will also need to allocate space for the array of pointers, maybe there you could use [`malloc()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/malloc.3.html).